# Cloudbees file logging options

Tags: cloudbees

It seems cloudbees writes the logs only to stream and not to a file. I need to save my logs. Can I use any option other than papertrail to store/retreive log files? Can I listen to the some input stream and get feed of logs? Can I dump logs directly to Amazon S3?

Answer (score 0):

As filesystem isn't persistent we also don't provide file based logging. We don't provide a platform helper to store logs to S3, as papertrails offers a comparable persistent solution with better performances and dedicated service.

You can for sure use your favorite logging framework and custom extensions to get log stored on S3 or other if you prefer this option.